# silverlight bubble chart : Change the visual state of the a bubble in a bubble chart through code

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have created a bubble chart using silverlight toolkit. It has a bubble series which is bound to a data source SampleData1 containing attributes : X,Y,size

Now I have 2 input boxes  to read values X and Y from user and a submit  button.I want to do following:
-  when user enters X , Y vales and clicks on submit button,  a bubble correspoding to the X,Y values should be highlighted.

As far as I know, I can higlight a bubble by using VisualStateMangaer :

> VisualStateManager.GoToState(BubbleRef, "Selected", true);

However, I don't know how to get the bubble reference from the X,Y values.
Is there a way to do this ? thanks in advance

Alternative : How to bind a visualStateMangaer to a property (e.g IsHighlighted) such that when I make this property true , Bubble is autmatically higlighted ?

Comment: Some clarification needed.  Are you talking about the X and Y value of a specific bubble OR are you talking about an X and Y value that may fall into the area of the disc of a bubble?

Comment: I am talking about X,Y values of a specific bubble. X ,Y are NOT the coordinates of the chart. They could be any attributes like age, population etc.